# Django got error cannot import name AppRegistryNotReady while importing session_security

Tags: python, django

I am facing one error on Django 1.5.12 while importing `session_security.middleware`. I got the message below:

```
File "/opt/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware session_security.middleware: "cannot import name AppRegistryNotReady"
```

Can someone advise please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your version of `django-session-security` does not support Django 1.5. The current release [2.6.1](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/2.6.1/README.rst#requirements) supports Django 1.8 - 2.0.

You could try installing version [2.3.2](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/2.3.3/README.rst#requirements), which is the last version to support Django 1.4+ according to the readme. [2.3.3](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/2.6.1/README.rst#requirements) requires Django 1.7+.

However note that Django 1.5 is years out of date and missing security fixes. You should upgrade.